# wrapped c/c++ object of type QWidget has been deleted

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
class window25(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            super(window25,self).__init__()
            self.lineedit=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.checkbox=QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
            self.optBox=QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
            self.btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("press me")
            self.guichange()
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.guichange)
            self.show()
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
    def guichange(self):
        try:
            wid=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    #        self.setCentralWidget()
            myLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            myLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
            myLayout.addWidget(random.choice([self.lineedit,self.checkbox,self.optBox]))
            wid.setLayout(myLayout)    
            self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)


app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window25()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was trying to do the experiment.Although I know about QStackedWidget to change windows but I tried something else that is pressing a button randomly changes the mainWindow Central widget.After a couple of success(i.e. pressing button 3,4 times work correctly") but after that I got an error

> wrapped c/c++ object of type QCheckBox has been deleted
>
> wrapped c/c++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted

i am unable to understand which statement caused this error and why or where I am wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the implementation and philosophy of Qt, reviewing the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details) observed:

> [...]
>
> QObjects organize themselves in object trees. When you create a
> QObject with another object as parent, the object will automatically
> add itself to the parent's children() list. The parent takes ownership
> of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its
> destructor. You can look for an object by name and optionally type
> using findChild() or findChildren().
>
> [...]

As he says if the parent destroys the children too, and since all widgets have `QObject` as their predecessor, they also comply with those rules.

**But why are some widget destroyed?**

Each time you use `setCentralWidget()` the object that was previously the central widget is deleted.

**What are the children of the CentralWidget()?**

when the widgets are attached to a layout, these widgets are set as the parent to the widget that uses that layout.

```
wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()   
myLayout.addWidget(tmp)    
wid.setLayout(myLayout)    
self.setCentralWidget(wid)
```

**Why is not QPushButton eliminated?**

What happens with `QPushButton` and sometimes with the other widgets is that before using `setCentralWidget()`, that is deleting the parent, it is changed from the parent:

```
myLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # some parent
myLayout.addWidget(self.btn)     # a new parent is established
[...]
self.setCentralWidget(wid)       # elimination of the old parent
```

Finally I will explain a random example using the following code:

```
class window25(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            super(window25,self).__init__()
            self.lineedit=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            self.lineedit.setObjectName("QLineEdit")
            self.checkbox=QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
            self.checkbox.setObjectName("QCheckBox")
            self.optBox=QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
            self.optBox.setObjectName("QRadioButton")
            self.btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("press me")
            self.guichange()
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.guichange)
            self.show()
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
    def guichange(self):
        try:
            print("\ncall guichange")
            wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            wid.setObjectName("wid-{}".format(self.counter))
            myLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            myLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
            tmp = random.choice([self.lineedit,self.checkbox,self.optBox])
            myLayout.addWidget(tmp)
            wid.setLayout(myLayout)    
            wid.destroyed.connect(lambda obj: print("delete: ",obj.objectName()))
            tmp.destroyed.connect(lambda obj: print("delete: ",obj.objectName()))
            self.setCentralWidget(wid)
            print("add: {} parent: {}".format(tmp.objectName(),tmp.parent().objectName()))
            self.counter += 1

        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
```

Explanation:

```
call guichange
QLineEdit                      # tmp is QLineEdit
add: QLineEdit parent: wid-0   # set to wid-0 as the parent of QLineEdit

call guichange
QLineEdit                      # tmp is QLineEdit
add: QLineEdit parent: wid-1   # set to wid-1 as new parent of QLineEdit
delete:  wid-0                 # delete old parent

call guichange
QRadioButton                     # tmp is QRadioButton
add: QRadioButton parent: wid-2  # set to wid-2 as the parent of QRadioButton
delete:  wid-1                   # delete old parent
delete:  QLineEdit               # message printed by the lambda function 
delete:  QLineEdit               # indicating that QLineEdit has been deleted

call guichange
wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted # you want to use QLineEdit 
                                                        # but it had been removed
                                                        # previously causing 
                                                        # that error message
```

---

If you want to exchange widgets the appropriate option is `QStackedWidget` as I show below:

```
class window25(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window25, self).__init__()
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.optBox = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("press me")
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        myLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.checkbox)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.optBox)
        wid.setLayout(myLayout) 
        myLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        myLayout.addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        self.guichange()
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.guichange)

    def guichange(self):
        widget = random.choice([self.lineedit,self.checkbox,self.optBox])
        self.stacked.setCurrentWidget(widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=window25()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```